# Select specific cluster with prefix in VMware cluster from Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

I'm using the below playbook to list all the VMware cluster belonging to my datacenter, but I need to select a specific cluster  containing `LAB` in the cluster name.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files: 1credentials.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Gather cluster info from given datacenter
      community.vmware.vmware_cluster_info:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
        datacenter: SDx-CoE-T7
        validate_certs: no
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: cluster_info

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_info }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.keys() | list | to_yaml }}"
```

I'm trying to use `selectattr()`, but, I am not able to get the exact syntax. Can you please suggest the best option to filter the cluster name containing `LAB`.

Below is the playbook output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Gather cluster info from given datacenter] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "clusters": {
            "TEST_LAB": {
                "datacenter": "TEST_CoE-T7",
                "drs_default_vm_behavior": "fullyAutomated",
                "drs_enable_vm_behavior_overrides": true,
                "drs_vmotion_rate": 3,
                "enable_ha": false,
                "enabled_drs": false,
                "enabled_vsan": false,
                "ha_admission_control_enabled": true,
                "ha_failover_level": 1,
                "ha_host_monitoring": "enabled",
                "ha_restart_priority": [
                    "medium"
                ],
                "ha_vm_failure_interval": [
                    30
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failure_window": [
                    -1
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failures": [
                    3
                ],
                "ha_vm_min_up_time": [
                    120
                ],
                "ha_vm_monitoring": "vmMonitoringDisabled",
                "ha_vm_tools_monitoring": [
                    "vmMonitoringDisabled"
                ],
                "hosts": [],
                "moid": "domain-c28615",
                "resource_summary": {
                    "cpuCapacityMHz": 0,
                    "cpuUsedMHz": 0,
                    "memCapacityMB": 0,
                    "memUsedMB": 0,
                    "pMemAvailableMB": 0,
                    "pMemCapacityMB": 0,
                    "storageCapacityMB": 0,
                    "storageUsedMB": 0
                },
                "tags": [],
                "vsan_auto_claim_storage": false
            },
            "TEST_LaaS": {
                "datacenter": "TEST_CoE-T7",
                "drs_default_vm_behavior": "fullyAutomated",
                "drs_enable_vm_behavior_overrides": true,
                "drs_vmotion_rate": 3,
                "enable_ha": true,
                "enabled_drs": true,
                "enabled_vsan": false,
                "ha_admission_control_enabled": true,
                "ha_failover_level": 1,
                "ha_host_monitoring": "enabled",
                "ha_restart_priority": [
                    "medium"
                ],
                "ha_vm_failure_interval": [
                    30
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failure_window": [
                    -1
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failures": [
                    3
                ],
                "ha_vm_min_up_time": [
                    120
                ],
                "ha_vm_monitoring": "vmMonitoringDisabled",
                "ha_vm_tools_monitoring": [
                    "vmMonitoringDisabled"
                ],
                "hosts": [
                    {
                        "folder": "/TEST_CoE-T7/host/TEST_LaaS",
                        "name": "172.17.65.84"
                    },
                    {
                        "folder": "/TEST_CoE-T7/host/TEST_LaaS",
                        "name": "172.17.65.85"
                    },
                    {
                        "folder": "/TEST_CoE-T7/host/TEST_LaaS",
                        "name": "172.17.168.202"
                    }
                ],
                "moid": "domain-c861",
                "resource_summary": {
                    "cpuCapacityMHz": 158040,
                    "cpuUsedMHz": 17494,
                    "memCapacityMB": 786073,
                    "memUsedMB": 361592,
                    "pMemAvailableMB": 0,
                    "pMemCapacityMB": 0,
                    "storageCapacityMB": 22707456,
                    "storageUsedMB": 14326118
                },
                "tags": [],
                "vsan_auto_claim_storage": false
            }
        },
        "failed": false
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "[TEST_Automation, TEST_LAB, TEST_LaaS,]\n"
}
```

If I use ansible version 2.9.27, I'm getting below error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cluster_info.clusters | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains','Common')| items2dict | list }}): items2dict requires a list, got <class 'generator'> instead."}
```

I tried with below one removing items2dict:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains','TEST') | list }}"
```

It is giving the below output but I need only the key: TEST_Lab

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "key": "TEST_LAB",
            "value": {
                "drs_default_vm_behavior": "partiallyAutomated",
                "drs_enable_vm_behavior_overrides": true,
                "drs_vmotion_rate": 3,
                "enable_ha": false,
                "enabled_drs": true,
                "enabled_vsan": false,
                "ha_admission_control_enabled": true,
                "ha_failover_level": 1,
                "ha_host_monitoring": "enabled",
                "ha_restart_priority": [
                    "medium"
                ],
                "ha_vm_failure_interval": [
                    30
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failure_window": [
                    -1
                ],
                "ha_vm_max_failures": [
                    3
                ],
                "ha_vm_min_up_time": [
                    120
                ],
                "ha_vm_monitoring": "vmMonitoringDisabled",
                "ha_vm_tools_monitoring": [
                    "vmMonitoringDisabled"
                ],
                "tags": [],
                "vsan_auto_claim_storage": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `selectattr`, you need to have a value to filter on, not a key. But transforming a dictionary into a list, containing the key and value is as simple as using the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) filter, in Ansible.
Then, to come back to your dictionary, just use the *"antonym"* filter, [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries).

So, your debug task ends up being:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      cluster_info.clusters
      | dict2items
      | selectattr('key','contains','LAB')
      | items2dict
```

---

Given the task, with a reduced dictionary for readability:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: |-
      cluster_info.clusters
      | dict2items
      | selectattr('key','contains','LAB')
      | items2dict
  vars:
    cluster_info:
      clusters:
        TEST_LAB:
          datacenter: TEST_CoE-T7
          drs_default_vm_behavior: fullyAutomated
        TEST_LaaS:
          datacenter: TEST_CoE-T7
          drs_default_vm_behavior: fullyAutomated
```

This will yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    cluster_info.clusters
    | dict2items
    | selectattr('key','contains','LAB')
    | items2dict
  : TEST_LAB:
      datacenter: TEST_CoE-T7
      drs_default_vm_behavior: fullyAutomated
```

Comment: If I use ansible version 2.9.27, I'm getting below error:```fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cluster_info.clusters | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains','Common')| items2dict | list }}): items2dict requires a list, got <class 'generator'> instead."}```.

Comment: Add a `| list` before the `dict2items`. This happens because, on this old, **unmaintained** version, `selectattr` return a generator and not a list.

Comment: I did and the code is ```msg: "{{ cluster_info.clusters | list | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains',TEST)| items2dict | list }}"``` post which I'm still getting templating error ```TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cluster_info.clusters | list | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains','Common')| items2dict | list }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'list'> instead."}```

Comment: before the `ìtems2dict` too.

Comment: Getting the below error: ```TASK [debug] ********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cluster_info.clusters | list | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains',TEST)| list | items2dict | list }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'list'> instead."}``` even after list to the msg syntax: ```var: "{{ cluster_info.clusters | list | dict2items | selectattr('key','contains',SDX)| list | items2dict | list }}"```